# How to write this callback code using arrow function?

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

Beginner in JavaScript and arrow function here.

I try to change the following syntax into arrow function format but failed.

Normal function:

```
function add(a, b, callback) {
    document.write(`The sum of ${a} and ${b} is ${a + b}.` + `<br>`);
    callback();
}

function secondLine(){
document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");
}

add(1,2,secondLine)
```

Arrow function

```
((a, b, callback) => {
document.write(`The sum of ${a} and ${b} is ${a + b}.` + `<br>`);
callback();
})

(secondLine() => {
document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");
})

(1,2,secondLine)
```

The console only returns

```
The sum of function(){document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");} and undefined is function(){document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");}undefined.
```

Should I not use arrow function in callback? If I really want to use callback, how should the syntax be typed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, if you want to declare the function as a separate variable (`secondLine`), there is absolutely no reason to make it an arrow function. And definitely you should just keep `add` as it is.

Comment: Then for the sake of training arrow function, yes, definitely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
(function(){
  var add = (a, b, callback) => {
    document.write(`The sum of ${a} and ${b} is ${a + b}.` + `<br>`);
    callback();
  }

  var secondLine = () => {
    document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");
  }
  add(1,2,secondLine);
})();
```

Comment: Great! You helped me! But I'd like to know what is the use of the brackets before the semi-colon in the last line. Does it mean to invoke the whole function? If not, how should I understand?

Comment: @ronzenith, the `()` at the end indicates  that the function is a *self-invoking* function and will invoke/execute the code at the parsing time:)

Comment: @ronzenith self-invoking functions are called IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions) and can be incredibly useful if you want to execute a function immediately. They also help you encapsulate functionality inside of a single function call and allow you to avoid polluting the global scope.

Here's some more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: @Mamun Why did you add the IIFE to the OPs code though for no reason?

Comment: @Bergi, I noticed that OP tries to use that in his code sample:)

Comment: @Mamun I don't think he did omit the semicolons and the `add` variable on purpose.

Comment: Maybe off-topic here. I'm rather confused with IIFEs, sometimes I come across function with () and some with (). For example I follow the YouTube example and extract a part below. 
There is a function called getPosts(). but when it is called in the end, no () is needed. May I know why?

//function getPosts() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let output = '';
        posts.forEach((post, index) => {
            output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`
        })
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    }, 500)
};

createPost({ title: 'Post Three', body: 'Post Three here' }, getPosts)

Comment: @ronzenith Because `createPost(…, getPosts)` does not call `getPosts`! It passes the function itself as an argument value to the `createPost` call. Inside that function, it will get called - with `()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your original code, it's really fine to not use arrow functions. Having `add` and `secondLine` declared as variables allows to make any number of similar calls, like `add(3,7,secondLine)` and `add(42,0,secondLine)`.

If you don't want to reuse `secondLine` (i.e. you need it only as an argument for that single call), you can convert it into an unnamed function expression though and write it right in the place of the argument:

```
add(1, 2, function() {
    document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");
});
```

This you now can easily change into an arrow function:

```
add(1, 2, () => {
    document.write("The callback must be printed after addition.");
});
```